# No suitable name with generic and HAS-A relation in Java

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, cdi

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractElement<V extends AbstractElementView, M extends AbstractElementModel> {

    @Inject
    private Instance<V> viewInstance;

    protected Instance<V> getViewInstance() {
        return viewInstance;
    }

    public abstract V newView();
}

public abstract class AbstractElementModel<E extends AbstractElement> {}

public abstract class AbstractElementView<E extends AbstractElement, M extends AbstractElementModel> {}

public class Temp<V extends TempView, M extends TempModel> extends AbstractElement<V, M>{
    @Override
    public V newView() {
        return getViewInstance().select(TempView.class).get();//LINE X
    }
}

public class TempModel<E extends Temp> extends AbstractElementModel<E> {}

public class TempView<E extends Temp, M extends TempModel> extends AbstractElementView<E, M>{}
```

Element consists of view and model. View knows about element and model, model knows only about element (don't ask what pattern is this - this is not important). I have AbstractElement and Temp. Temp can also be inherited. In Temp I need to override newView method. However, I get `not suitable method found for select` at `LINE X`. What is my mistake?

EDIT : Inject and Instance are

```
javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
javax.inject.Inject;
```

Comment: Missing `Instance` in your code.

Comment: @lexicore Sorry, can't find. Could you provide more details.

Comment: You code has this `private Instance<V> viewInstance;` but you didn't include `Instance` in your code snippet. What do you mean you can't find?
`

Comment: @lexicore I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a lot of raw types as type parameters. This will not go well.

`getViewInstance()` in `Temp` gives you `Instance<V>` where `V extends TempView`.

`viewInstance.select` is applicable to `Class<U> subtype` where `U extends V` (which extends `TempView`). `V` can be any subclass of `TempView`, so `TempView` can't substitute `U` and therefore you can't pass `Class<TempView>` to `select`.